# Question about limit with two functions

Tags: limits, functions

[Limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfCNu.jpg)

$f(x) = x^2 - 1, x<2$ and $f(x) = 2 + x, x>=2$

Answer : $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 2^2 - 1 = 3$

Is the logic is correct here?

Because theres a function outside 2. Then we could use the first function to calculate? Or is it unable to calculated because its limit is 2?

Comment: You have to calculate two limits:   1. the limit with $x\to 2$ from the left, then from the right.

Comment: So the solution is x^2 - 1 = 3 and 2 + 2 = 4?

Comment: Indeed, two distinct left/right limits, hence no "both-sided" limit. But please don't rely on an image: [type your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). And choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: @Few You found correct from left and right, but when they are not the same, it is said the limit does not exist.

Comment: @coffeemath so in other words, if we have 2 functions that able to be calculated then theres no limit?

Comment: you can also say that the function is discontinuous at x=2

Comment: @Few It is very important that, in addition to having two functions whose limit is able to be calculated as x approaches a from either side, it is the case that the two calculations give *different* results, in order to say no limit. [you didn't mention this in your last comment] If the two calculations happen to be the same result, then the limit does exist and is the common value of the two results from left and right.

Comment: @04-jayeshkumargupta But note that if the function happens not to be defined at x=c, one does not say it is discontinuous there, only [if the two one-sided limits differ] that the limit of the function at c does not exist. A function not even defined at x=c is not said to be discontinuous at c.

Comment: It's a piecewise function when the function is described in different ways on different sides of a boundary. The limit of a piecewise function exists only if the limit of both functions at that boundary are the same. $4\ne 3$ so the limit doesn't exist at this boundary. As oppose to $ f(x)=0, x<0, f (x)=x, x\ge 0$. Then $f(0^-)=f(0^+)$ so it has a limit at $x=0$.